# Error creating bean with name 'countryController' defined in file

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to make addresses where country has many states and and in states there are many districts and in districts there are many municipalities.

My CountryDTO:

```java
package com.part.firstProject.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;


@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Component
public class CountryDTO {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<StatesDTO> states;
}
```

MyCountryEntity:

```java
package com.part.firstProject.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name="Country")
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="country_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="country_name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private States states;
}
```

MyCountryController:

```java
package com.part.firstProject.controller;

import com.part.firstProject.dto.CountryDTO;
import com.part.firstProject.entity.Country;
import com.part.firstProject.service.CountryService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CountryController {
    private  CountryService countryService;

    @Autowired
    public CountryController(CountryService countryService){
        this.countryService=countryService;
    }
    @GetMapping("/getCountry")
    public ResponseEntity<?>findAll(){
        List<CountryDTO> countries=countryService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(countries,countries.size()>0? HttpStatus.OK:HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

MYCountryServiceImpl:

```java
package com.part.firstProject.service;

import com.part.firstProject.dto.CountryDTO;
import com.part.firstProject.entity.Country;
import com.part.firstProject.repository.CountryRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CountryServiceImpl implements CountryService {
    CountryRepository countryRepository;
    @Autowired
    CountryServiceImpl(CountryRepository countryRepository){
        this.countryRepository=countryRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public List<CountryDTO> findAll() {
     List<CountryDTO> countryDTOS= countryRepository.findAll();
        if(countryDTOS.size()>0){
            return countryDTOS;
        }else{
            return new ArrayList<CountryDTO>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CountryDTO findById(int id) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(CountryDTO countryList) {
            countryRepository.save(countryList);
    }
}
```

MyCountryRepository:

```java
package com.part.firstProject.repository;
import com.part.firstProject.dto.CountryDTO;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<CountryDTO, Integer> {

}
```

In my MainApplication:

```java
package com.part.firstProject;

import com.part.firstProject.service.AddressService;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FirstProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(AddressService addressService) {
        return args -> {
            // read json and write to db
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().
                                getResourceAsStream("/nepal-data.json"))));
                System.out.println("Users Saved!");
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Unable to save users: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I was expecting this will run smoothly, but I am facing the following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'countryController' defined in file 
> Error creating bean with name 'countryServiceImpl' defined in file 
> Error creating bean with name 'countryRepository' defined in com.part.firstProject.repository 
> Not a managed type: class com.part.firstProject.dto.CountryDTO

Answer (score 0):

I you see you are trying to fetch data from a database for *countrydto*:

`List<CountryDTO> countries=countryService.findAll();`

However, the error is saying that CountryDTO *is not a managed class*, meaning it’s expected to be an entity.

Either you need it to be of type `@Entity` to fire Spring data jpa queries or refactor to only call repository methods on the entity only.

Comment: But how, when i have given CountryDTO in CountryRepository?

Comment: add `@Entity` annotation to your dtos

Comment: But i have created Entity for country already, Will that not affect My tables in database?

Comment: countryService.findAll(); should return countries, then you can create a dto with that countries using new keyword.
All repository calls should return only entity objects that is what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use @ComponentScan("basePackage name) in the main function of a web application. Try this.